# Bind for taking out melee wep in TF2?

Tags: team-fortress-2, source-engine

I'd like a bind to take out my melee.This is mainly for powerjack efficiency, but it would help for market gardener.

Answer (score 5):

I think by default your '3' key is bound to execute 'slot3' which simply brings up your third weapon in mostly every source game and,  in TF2's case it is always the melee.

If you're unsure how to bind however, open your developer console (needs to be enabled in Keyboard/Mouse Settings > Advanced) and enter:

***bind "3" "slot3"***

Replacing '3' with whatever you'd like to press.
This can also be done with slot1, slot2, slot4 and slot5 for all classes, including things like the Spy's sapper and disguise kit, along with Engineer's Build and Destruction PDA.

Hope this helped you out.